# How to use Redis / Node.Js on a production server

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, production

I get what Redis and Node.js are but i don't understand how to run them on a live server. Locally its an install and you use the command line to get them running but i don't know how to install them on a live server.

I've already browsed around a bit but im still confused and also isn't Node.JS a server itself so its like running a server on a server? wouldn't that have effects on performance and what not?

I'm just confused on how it would work, any explanation will be great.. thanks

Comment: Its the same you run in your test environment. start the redis server, then start your node app. You can use a separate server for redis if you want. that depends on the size of your application

Comment: @zamil this is what im saying how do you "start the server" i dont get how it would get on the server in the first place, you cant execute windows commands on an external server right?

Comment: What "server" do you mean?  If you have a computer that you want to use as a server, install redis and node on it.  If you are using a hosting provider, you either need a virtual machine you can install your own software on, or you need to find a hosting provider that supports nodejs and redis, and their instructions should tell you what to do.

Comment: take any system that is exposed to internet and have a public ip. install redis, start redis server. whats the confusion here. In my case its an ubuntu machiene. install redis and then start it.

Comment: It seems people forget not everyone learns to same, it doesnt matter to me that you think there should be no confusion the problem is that there is.

@JasonGoemaat when i say server i mean node.js i didnt know that some hosting providers allow it as an installation i thought you just put it in the server like you would in development i.e install node.js globally on your computer and then within your dev environment put the server.js file in a folder somewhere and make reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis & Node.js = Software

You install those on a physical machine, a computer. A node.js server is not a physical server, but an application that *can* handle HTTP requests. Normally, a node.js server runs on a port on a physical machine. So any HTTP requests sent to that port are handled by the node.js application. You can use a webserver, which is another piece of software that handles HTTP requests, like Nginx or Apache to manage multiple domains on a physical machine (the server). Redis also runs on a physical machine and listens on a specified port.

For example, I have a VPS with 4 websites on it managed by Nginx. Two of those websites are Laravel projects that connect to a MySQL server (on another machine) and to a Redis server on the same machine. The other two are node.js applications which don't need a database or Redis, so they just listen on their own ports and Nginx proxies all connections to their domainnames to those ports.

So you're not actually running a server on a server, but you're running software that handles certain things on a server.

Comment: This is making sense to me now, its just the way i am learning node.js has lead me to believe differenlty. 

I hope you understand that local vs production is different which is where my confusion came from. 

Is there no way to install a node.js / redis application on the same server thats running the site? its a big powerful server and im not the one in charge of buying / distributing the server so it would be ideal for it to all work on 1 server.

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius Yes, that's possible. Have a look into Docker, it will be useful. With Docker, you can also run the exact same environment on your production server and on your local machine. Docker can also help you a lot to understand how it all works together.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question youve cleared so much up!

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to run a node service. I strongly recommend docker to run everything but here is a short list of the most popular ones:

- https://www.docker.com/  https://hub.docker.com/_/node/
- http://pm2.keymetrics.io/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever (seems like a bit outdated)

Comment: Thank you for this ill look into it